# NAT traversal when one peer has static IP

Tags: networking, nat

If I have a server that is allocated a static IP, and that server sits behind a NAT controlled router will my server always be able to send a response directly back to the IP & Port of the sending client?

My server may be a game server or some other type of UDP based service, but it will always be inside a NAT controlled network, and reciving UDP packets from externally connected clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if server responds to that IP and port client will always receive response back ?

Yes - the router(s) in charge of the NAT will maintain state such that returned traffic is translated back to the correct, original client. This is true of any layer 3 traffic (protocol and port doesn't matter).

Consider the following:

```
Client IP                 Client public IP           Server public IP
192.168.10.151 <-router-> 86.45.75.12  <-internet->  125.12.67.35
```

Corresponding traffic flow:

```
1) Client request traffic:
---------------------------------------------------> arrives with source of 86.45.75.12

2) Server response traffic sent back to 86.45.75.12:
                                     <--------------------------

3) Translated back to 192.168.10.151:
<-----------------------------------
```

The server will see traffic with a source of `86.45.75.12`, and will send response traffic back to that IP. The router handling the NATing for the client will maintain state such that it knows response traffic coming from `125.12.67.35`, going back to `86.45.75.12`, will be correctly translated and routed to the original source, `192.168.10.151`.

Comment: This is how I expect this to work, however I heart about different types of NAT. Is it true for all types ?

Comment: Yes, there really aren't different kinds of NAT - you're either translating IP (NAT) or port (PAT) or both; regardless of what you're translating, the routers doing the translation will also remember that translation and will get response traffic back to where it needs to be.